# Language parameter while embedding Google map in website

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am trying to embed Google map on my multi-lingual website. I want to translate entire google map interface depending on my current language. Entire interface not getting translated (links such as "Singin, Get Directions"). I facing this problem only after embedding the MAP CODE in the HTML and then looking at the MAP from within the web page.

Here are the steps that I followed

1. Get embed code by adding "?hl=ja" in url
2. Change search language to japan then get the embed code
3. Change browser default language
4. Set domain to google.co.jp

Please guide me to achieve this

Sample code

```
/***Starts here***/
<iframe src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m14!1m8!1m3!1d1619.1747385460585!2d139.7973569!3d35.7422141!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!3m3!1m2!1s0x60188e5cee002b37%3A0xe25ef9bf0ae8fb71!2sSenjuohashi+Station!5e0!3m2!1szh-CN!2s!4v1412779067090" width="600" height="450" frameborder="0" style="border:0"></iframe>
/***Ends here***/
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

1. Create your map using https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/embed/start
2. Add your API key
3. Generate the iframe code
4. Add *&language=ja* to the iframe src

Hope this helps.